# AngularJS ngSrc - default path if current path not exist

Tags: angularjs, image

I use this image html tag with angularJS'S ngSrc like this:

```
 <img data-ng-src="assets/img/{{documentFile.ending}}.PNG" alt="" title="Dateiendung {{documentFile.ending}}" />
```

Is there a way that ngSrc use another path if **documentFile.ending** does not exist - something like **if not exist than use a default path**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ngSrc`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) directive doesn't have that functionality.

You can check if a resource exists by using the [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service:

```js
// app.js
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('app', []);

})();

// main.controller.js
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('app').controller('MainController', MainController);

  MainController.$inject = ['$http'];

  function MainController($http) {

    var vm = this;

    // set image uri's
    var myImageUri = "http://example.com/myimagedoesntexist.png";
    var myFallbackImageUri = "http://placehold.it/350x150?text=My+fallback+image";

    // make a http get request to check if the image exists
    $http.get(myImageUri).then(function() {

      // successful response status code so image exists

      // use image uri
      vm.myImageUri = myImageUri;

    }, function() {

      // non-success response status code so image does not exist

      // use fallback image uri
      vm.myImageUri = myFallbackImageUri;

    });

  }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as MainCtrl">

  <img data-ng-src="{{MainCtrl.myImageUri}}" alt="..." title="" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the logical operator `||`, which return the value of the second operand if the first is falsy

```
<img data-ng-src="assets/img/{{documentFile.ending || 'default-image.png'}}.PNG" alt="" title="Dateiendung {{documentFile.ending}}" />
```

If `documentFile.ending` has a truthy value(i.e. an string) but the image doesn't exists on the server, you can write a simple directive for handle the error.

```js
angular.module('test', [])
  .controller('test', function ($scope) {
    $scope.correct_image = 'https://unsplash.it/200';
    $scope.wrong_image = 'https://unsplas123123h.it/200';
  })
  .directive('imageDispatch', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('load', function () {
          console.log('image loaded');
        }).bind('error', function () {
          element.attr('src', 'http://www.safexone.com/images/old/default.gif');
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="test">
  <h3>Correct image</h3>
  <img ng-src="{{correct_image}}" image-dispatch />
  <h3>Wrong image</h3>
  <img ng-src="{{wrong_image}}" image-dispatch />
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @georgeawg Correct.  And It'll be considered false if `documentFile.ending` is either `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: but **documentFile.ending** does have a value but the PNG does not exist at server - is there also a possibility for this case?

Comment: @user3318489 yes, it's possible, I update my answer, take a look at it

Comment: @georgeawg yes, it's correct, you can see the falsy values here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy